# uploading photo from iphone on web form down samples and assigns the photo a random name

Tags: ios, iphone, forms, express, web-applications

I have created a small web app that accepts photos and uploads them to a local server using react and expressjs. It is meant to run entirely on my local intranet. As a test I sftp'd the photos from my phone to my linux server is shows the file as 5.1mb and a consistent name of IMG_XXXX.jpg. However, when I upload through the web form the photo is a random UUID.jpeg, and the file size is 1.5mb. Why? Even when choosing the photo I am given a selection of "Large, Medium, Small, or Actual". I chose actual and it tells me the photo is 5.1MB. Could these be a setting in expressjs or is this iphone specific?

Comment: Maybe there is a layer on the backend that processes images? Resizing/Compressing and changing their names?

Comment: thanks @realtimez, but this is not the case. I took the photo 5.1mb photo that I sftp'd from my iphone to my server and uploaded from my desktop. No down sampling took place. My next step is to use the FilesAPI in the browser to display some information about the photos before uploading.

Comment: It seems this was not possible. That the iphone will always downsample the photos through a web form. The solution was to use an app. I wanted this to be a quick and dirty project for my wife and I to archive and share photos of our son on plex with family. I set up nextcloud easily in an afternoon. It has worked well.